# How to inherit e-bean models from parent model without creating the parent table?

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an abstract parent class `Person`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class Person extends Model {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int gender;
}
```

and two child classes, which inherits first:

```
@Entity
class User extends Person {}


@Entity
class BookAuthor extends Person {}
```

I want to create two tables: `user` and `book_author`. Table for model `Person` should not be created. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABLE PER CLASS inheritance strategy is not supported by EBean for now. See https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/116 and http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/

You can use [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation.

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Person extends Model {...}

@Entity
public class User extends Person {...}

@Entity
public class BookAuthor extends Person {...}
```